# Verifying a string is not empty/null in an If condition

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm writing a script that will accept user input via `Read-Host` (set to `$String`), and I want to avoid any issues that could be caused by having a blank value for the variables. Since I'll be using this a lot, I want to implement it into a function that verifies no invalid characters are being used.

I thought I could use an if statement with `![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($String)` as one of the conditions:

```
Function Test-ValidCharacters ($String, $ValidCharacters) {  
  if (($String -match $ValidCharacters) -and (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($String)))) {
    return $true
  }
  else {return $false}
}
```

I also tried this:

```
Function Test-ValidCharacters ($String, $ValidCharacters) {  
  if (($String -match $ValidCharacters) -and ($String -ceq "")) {
    return $true
  }
  else {return $false}
}
```

In both of these cases, I can just hit enter when presented with the $String's Read-Host prompt and the script will behave as if the function returned `$True` (and then later encounter fatal errors). The other half works - if I include characters not specified by `$ValidCharacters` the function returns `$False` as expected.

I am sure I'm missing something here. I even tried doing a second nested if statement and got the same result.

Edit: Here's the code snippet where I call the function and notice the issue.

```
$ValidCharacters = '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
$FirstN = Read-Host -Prompt "New user's first name"
While (Test-ValidCharacters $FirstN $ValidCharacters -eq $false) {
  Write-Output "$FirstN contains illegal characters. A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 are accepted."
  $FirstN = Read-Host -Prompt "New user's first name"
}
```

Comment: Try `If(!([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($String))){`. Also, without knowing what `$ValidCharacters` is it is really hard to help.

Comment: You could use `[validatescript({$_.Trim() -match '\w'})]$check = Read-Host 'User input here'` and avoid the need of the function :)

Comment: It's a range regex - '[a-zA-Z0-9]' - sorry I didn't include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$ValidCharacters` isn't itself an empty string and contains an *anchored* character-range regex ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)) that covers the *entire input string*, such as `^[a-z0-9./:]+$`, given that the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) matches any *substring* by default (note that a better name for the parameter is therefore something like `$ValidationRegex`):<sup>[1]</sup>

- In the first function definition, the RHS of your `-and` operation is redundant - it adds nothing to the conditional, because if `$String -match $ValidCharacters` is `$true`, then so is `! [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($String)`, by definition.
- Conversely, in the second function definition your `-and` operation *always returns `$false`*, because `$String -ceq ""` is by definition `$false`, if the LHS returned `$true`.

Assuming that your intent is to prevent empty or all-whitespace input and to ensure that any string - trimmed of incidental leading and/or trailing whitespace - is composed only of expected characters, use the following:

```sh
Function Test-ValidCharacters ($String, $ValidCharacters) {
  # Note: no strict need for `return`.
  $String.Trim() -match $ValidCharacters
}
```

---

<sup>[1] Alternatively, stick with `$ValidCharacters` and pass a regex that describes only a *single* valid character, such as `'[a-z0-9./:]'`, and construct the entire-string matching regex inside the function with `'^' + $ValidCharacters + '+$'`</sup>

Comment: Yes, the `$ValidCharacters` input is regex, '[a-zA-Z0-9]' in the test case. I tried your example to see if it behaved any differently, but I could still enter an empty response to `Read-Host` and it would evaluate as `$true`. I edited the original post to provide the use case of the function in case that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: @VictorArevalo You're always entering the `while` loop because: 1. your `regex` is wrong, instead of `'[^a-zA-Z0-9]'` it should be `'^[a-z0-9]'` **Note**, since `match` is case insensitive `A-Za-z` is not needed. thanks mklement0 for reminding of that :) 2. the condition on your `while` loop should encapsulate the function so PS will validate it first, on the other hand, asking if something is `$false` doesn't look very clean so for simplicity you can use `While (-not (Test-ValidCharacters $FirstN $ValidCharacters)) { .... }`

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon. My example regex should have been `^[a-z0-9./:]+$` (now fixed), given that `-match` matches any _substring_ by default.